# Optimal method to query number of times a user has an posted an entry

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table such as,

```
Column     |   Type
id            integer
job_id        integer
user_id       integer
date_posted  datetime
```

I want to write a query that breaks down the # of users that have posted their jobs once vs the number of users that have posted at least one job multiple times

```
    with user_jobs as (
                 select user_id, job_id, count(distinct date_posted) as num_posted
                 from table
                 group by user_id, job_id
                 )

Select SUM(Case when avg_num_posted > 1 then 1 end) as posted_multiple_times,
       SUM(Case when avg_num_posted = 1 then 1 end) as posted_once
FROM(
    Select user_id, avg(num_posted) as avg_num_posted
    from user_jobs
    Group by user_id) t
```

this gives me the output, but was wondering if there was a more optimal method, thanks!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your query uses `date_posted` which is not in the table you describe.  I also removed the MySQL database tag.  You tagged two databases and Presto seems much more intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can compare the number of distinct jobs to the number of job/date combinations.  Let me assume that a single job is never posted on the same date twice.  If that is the case:

```
Select sum(case when num_listings > num_jobs then 1 end) as posted_multiple_times,
       sum(case when num_listings = num_jobs then 1 end) as posted_once
from (select user_id, count(*) as num_listings, count(distinct job_id) as num_jobs
      from t
      group by user_id
     ) u;
```

If jobs can be posted twice on one day and you don't want to count that as a duplicate, then one method is:

```
Select sum(case when num_listings > num_jobs then 1 end) as posted_multiple_times,
       sum(case when num_listings = num_jobs then 1 end) as posted_once
from (select user_id, count(*) as num_listings,
             count(distinct job_id) as num_jobs
      from (select distinct user_id, job_id, date_posted from t) t
      group by user_id
     ) u;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i was calculting the number of times a user can post a job ( job_id ) either once or more than once, a job_id can be posted multiple times

Comment: @Chris90 . . . This returns what you want to know:  The number of users that have posted a job more than once and the number that have never done so.